# how to *not* to update functional component when its data has not changed

Tags: reactjs, jsx

So i have a react app where the root component is class based and holds the state as the follows:

```
this.state = {
    dataA: { //stuff here},
    dataB: { //stuff here}
}
```

where `dataA` gets passed to a child functional component A, and `dataB` gets passed down to a child functional component B.

but whenever i do `this.setState({dataA: { new state A cotnent }})`, component B also gets updated when though its data has not been changed.

Since component B is a functional component, i cannot implement `shouldComponentUpdate` method. So is there a way to not render component B when only `dataA` has changed? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383832/react-optimization-of-stateless-functional-components-through-shouldcomponentup

Comment: And you cannot implement B as a full React component?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because functional components always rerender when they receive props or state, even if the values haven't changed.

Instead, I would recommend converting the children from functional components to subclasses of [`PureComponent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent), which implements `shouldComponentUpdate` to shallow compare props and state. Note that all children of `PureComponents` should also be `PureComponents`, and if these conditions are too restricting you should implement `shouldComponentUpdate` yourself in a subclass of `Component`.